# Disable Spring Annotations Based on Profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mongodb

I'm using Spring 5.1+ with MongoDB. One of my classes is annotated with @Document so it gets picked up by MongoDB, however this is causing the program to fail tests as it times out waiting for the Mongo Service which isn't running.

Is there a way to disable the @Document annotation specifically based on the current profile? I've attempted doing things like:

```
@Profile("production")
@Document
public class MyRepoObject { ...
```

And using custom @Conditional annotations in the place of @Profile however that hasn't fixed the problem.

I'm certain it's the @Document annotation causing the error as the tests pass when I comment out the annotation.

Comment: You need to mock the service.

Comment: Do you mean mocking the class itself? I already mock out the MongoRepository in my testing, but only now adding the @Document has the problem shown up.

Comment: You should exclude mongo auto config from test. It's not the @Document that is waiting for mongo server

Comment: @JEY perfect! It works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution as JEY pointed out was to disable the Mongo Auto Configurations for the test environments.

I excluded MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class, MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class and all tests passed.